# Openshift Zombiejs

Tags: node.js, openshift, zombie.js

I have a Node.js/Express application which I'm trying to deploy to Openshift.

The server itself starts up properly and serves almost everything.

One request to the server opens up a Zombiejs browser, which then crawls some webpages.

When the browser tries to visit a webpage however, I get this error:

```
{ [Error: bind EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'bind' }
Possibly unhandled Error: bind EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at connect (net.js:747:21)
    at net.js:842:9
    at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
```

The browser fails as soon as I call `visit`:

```
browser.visit(menus_url).then(function () {
    // do things
});
```

Before doing the above, I start an Express-based server as follows:

```
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
app.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function() {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + server_port);
});
```

The server starts up fine, however as soon as I make a request that calls `browser.visit()` the error is raised.

## Update 11/15

I still haven't found a solution to this issue.

Comment: I believe the EACCES error means it can't access the specified port. (Although, unfortunately, it doesn't say which port that is...) Normally that happens when creating a server, not when running a client though. Are you running a local web server?

Comment: Ok, interesting. I just got a test app set up - just scrapes google.com and returns the html. It works fine on localhost, chokes with the same error as you on openshift. I'll let you know if I figure out why...

Comment: I think Zombiejs creates a local server on a port that OpenShift doesn't like

Comment: Okay I tried changing the port (I think) by using `Browser.localhost()` but I'm still encountering the same error.

Comment: So, the error you and I are getting is during the DNS lookup - but the app still hits the same error at the next step if you give it an IP address instead. (Also, a standard `require('http').get(...)` does still work fine, so it's not that all outgoing network connections fail, just (apparently) zombie.js ones...). I'm kind of stumped at this point (and running out of time), but I'll let you know if I do come up with anything...

Comment: One more note: zombie.js uses jsdom beneath the covers - and jsdom can load google.com just fine on openshift. So it's definitely something that zombie.js is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the browser is created, it tries to use the ip address of 0.0.0.0 to bind to (https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/src/zombie/browser.coffee#L1224) by default, which is not available on OpenShift for your use, you need it to bind to your OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP ip address, just like you use for your express server.  It looks like, at the top of the file that I linked to (https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/src/zombie/browser.coffee#L42), that one of the Browser options you can pass in is 'localAddress' when creating the Browser object, which should be the OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP.  I think that will get it fixed up for you.

Comment: I was thinking that this was the issue but I wasn't sure how to solve it. You're idea worked!